# SharePoint Online Issue with GetAuthenticationCookie returning "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: cookieHeader"

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I was authenticating SharePoint Online users via an API interface. For last couple of years it has been working fine. But Since Monday i am getting error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: cookieHeader

There is a code to generate HTTPClientHandler for SharePoint Online in API that is hosted on Azure.

```
HttpClientHandler result = new HttpClientHandler();
try
{

    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in userPassword) { securePassword.AppendChar(c); }

    SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    result.Credentials = credentials;

    string authCookieValue = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(hostWebURL));

    result.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(hostWebURL), authCookieValue);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

return result;
```

In the above line of code, we are getting null value of ‘authCookieValue’.

I also checked the value of ‘LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled’ through SharePoint Online Management Shell using below command, it was already true.

```
$TenantSettings = Get-SPOTenant
$TenantSettings.LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started getting the same error at some point. It was clearly a change on the Sharepoint Online side, because nothing had changed on my side for years.

I think the key line that fixed it for me was:

**ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;**

See below:

```
public async Task<List<SharepointDocumentDetail>> GetFileInfoFromSharepoint(string specificFolderUrl)
{
    // Once I added this, the error went away
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    List<SharepointDocumentDetail> ret = new List<SharepointDocumentDetail>();
     
    var restUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{1}')/Files?$expand=Files", this.Sharepoint_DocRootUrl, specificFolderUrl);
   
    //Creating Credentials
    var passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in this.Sharepoint_Password) passWord.AppendChar(c);
     
    var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(this.Sharepoint_User, passWord);
    
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential })
    { 
        Uri uri = new Uri(this.Sharepoint_DocRootUrl);
         
        // I was getting the error on this line
        handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, indeed that was the fix. Same worked for me some days back.